# Explain Natspec comment usage in a DAPP developent?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Why do we need Napspec comments. How can we use that Natspec comments during development of DAPP ?

Or Else the Natspec comments only for Ethereum Clients.

Answer (score 5):

Natspec was originally intended for annotating code for automatic documentation generation, with a command line flag for solidity to emit documentation as a JSON blob.

Natspec is also put to good use by the Dapple framework to emit logs. Here's an example:

```
contract Contract {
    function send (address addr, uint value) {
        //@info user `address addr` has deposit `uint value`eth
        [...]
        //@warn something happened: "`string message`"
    }
}
```

Running this code with `dapple test --report` will produce the following output:

```
INFO:  user 0x4cfcedde6a51e5f6b47da226e50c2bb8b055ee62 has deposit 200eth
WARN:  something happened: "a strange loop"
```

You can find the full documentation here:
 https://dapple.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging/

If you want to emit logs that can be read through web3js then you need to define and emit events in your contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleAuction {
    event HighestBidIncreased(address bidder, uint amount); // Event

    function bid() payable {
        // ...
        HighestBidIncreased(msg.sender, msg.value); // Triggering event
    }
}
```

You can then read the event using `web3.eth.filter`, where the topic should be the hash of the signature of the event.

Comment: Can we get this data through web3js channel in geth ethereum client. Or else where can i see the logging in ethereum geth clients.

Comment: No this data isn't accessible through web3js. If you want to read transaction logs you need to emit events and use web3.eth.filter.